# Replace Non alpha numeric characters with empty string MYSQL

Tags: mysql, alpha, numeric

```
select 
    file,
    REPLACE(FILE, '[:alnum:]'+'.'+,'') AS Collection
FROM
   CollectionData;


select 
    file,
REPLACE(FILENAME, '^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]','') AS Collection
FROM collectiondata;
```

I would like to replace all the non alpha numeric characters from the string including .file extensions from the string as given below.

```
AXS00003600.txt  to AXS
NXS4DG00003600.txt to NXS4DG
```

I am not able to replace the non alpha numeric data when I execute the above query. What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL contains no `REGEXP_REPLACE` operation. The ordinary `REPLACE` you're trying to use doesn't work with regular expressions. You'll need to do this in client code or maybe in a stored procedure.