# What's a good regex to include accented characters in a simple way?

Tags: regex

Right now my regex is something like this:

[a-zA-Z0-9] but it does not include accented characters like I would want to. I would also like - ' , to be included.

Comment: What language or regex engine are you using the regex in?

Comment: What do you mean by accented characters ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I guess it's one of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ä

Comment: You can also take a look at this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regular-expression-for-accented-characters-diacritics

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Accented Characters: DIY Character Range Subtraction**

If your regex engine allows it (and many will), this will work:

```
(?i)^(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿ])+$
```

Please see [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/14) (you can add characters to test).

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` sets case-insensitive mode
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿ])` matches one character...
- The lookahead `(?![×Þß÷þø])` asserts that the char is not one of those in the brackets
- `[-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿ]` allows dash, apostrophe, digits, letters, and chars in a wide accented range, from which we need to subtract
- The `+` matches that one or more times
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

[Extended ASCII Table](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: Should it not be À-Ž?

Comment: Not sure what language you are targeting, but you would also need to add œ and Œ for some (French among others), which falls outside the range described here...

Comment: Doesn't match `Šš`.

Comment: The demo is outdated and the regex from the answer should be copied to see it work.

Comment: Don't forget the period and comma for "Bob, Jr."

Comment: Doesn't match ğ and why do you not like Þßþø ? Islandic, German and Danish use these

Comment: Czech uses `Č` which isn't included in this regex. Extend it with `Ā-ſ` to cover `Latin Extended-A` which includes `Č`. If you also want to include `Latin Extended-B` use `ƀ-ȳ`. Then `[-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿ]` becomes `[-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿĀ-ſƀ-ȳ]`

Answer (score 29):

You put in your expression:

```
\p{L}\p{M}
```

This in Unicode will match:

- any letter character (L) from any language
- and marks (M)(i.e, a character that is to be combined with another: accent, etc.)

Comment: You were missing the /u - the complete regex is `/\p{L}+|\p{M}+/ugm` https://regex101.com/r/H59XSX/1

Comment: this addresses a different problem

Comment: thanks, only this nice solution works for East Europe string I have (Sójkowska)

Comment: Had a better mileage with `/[\p{L}\p{M}\d'-]+/ugm` which includes the hyphen (as requested),  an apostrophe (which usually makes sense, too) and numbers. If you don't want numbers (which can carry meaning just like a word), just leave the tailing `\d` away. https://regex101.com/r/O4WLyd/1

Answer (score 6):

A version without the exclusion rules:

```
^[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[...]` allows dash, apostrophe,
  digits, letters, and chars in a wide accented range,
- The `+` matches that one or more times
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Extended ASCII Table](https://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: Note that this misses numerous accented characters, including ӑ, ā, ć, n̈, and ō. It also includes characters the OP may not necessarily want, such as æ, Æ, Þ, þ, ß, and ø. See https://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/263

Comment: It does, however, cover the requirement of "good" coverage of the most common accented characters and easily modifiable to any readers requirements. æ, ć, n̈, ō, ß, and ø are in my requirement set. 
Great testing tool!

Comment: Version 264 of the regex linked above has more matches and is a little more eloquent using case insensitive matching `/(?![×Þß÷þ])[a-zá-žàấӑệởș]/ui` https://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/264 except unsure why the ø is removed (brød = bread in norwegian/danish)

Answer (score 5):

@NightCoder's answer works perfectly in PHP:

```php
    \p{L}\p{M}
```

and with no brittle whitelists. Note that to get it working in javascript you need to add the unicode `u` flag. Useful to have a working example in javascript...

```js
const text = `Crêpes are øh-so déclassée`
[ ...text.matchAll(  /[-'’\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+/giu  ) ]
```

will return something like...

```js
[
    {
        "0": "Crêpes",
        "index": 0
    },
    {
        "0": "are",
        "index": 7
    },
    {
        "0": "øh-so",
        "index": 11
    },
    {
        "0": "déclassée",
        "index": 17
    }
]
```

Here it is in a playground... https://regex101.com/r/ifgH4H/1/

And also some detail on those regex unicode categories... https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode

Answer (score 4):

Use a POSIX character class (http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

`[-'[:alpha:]0-9]` or `[-'[:alnum:]]`

The `[:alpha:]` character class matches whatever is considered "alphabetic characters" in your locale.

Comment: He wants accented characters. In many engines this will not match Ô, à, é etc.