# How to hide redundant french content in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date, french

I am working on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec8m2p6z/7/) which displays list of days and time (Timezone EST).

```
1 août 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
2 août 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 03:45 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
    ût 05:00 /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
```

The above fiddle is working in a way that I am hiding the date when the value is the same as previous row meaning not displaying a 
day on a row where the date is the same as the previous row so that there are visual breaks by date.

**Problem Statement:**

The above fiddle is working perfectly fine. The only issue which I am having is when the month is french then its 
not hiding out some french characters or anything after that. In the above o/p, ût is still visible which should not be.

```js
// we have to iterate backwards...
$($('.schedule-show').get().reverse()).each(function(i, div){
 let time = $(div).find('[data-timezone="et"]')
  let nextTime = $(div).find('+ .schedule-show [data-timezone="et"]')
  if(nextTime[0]){
   // check if they dates match
    if(nextTime.text().match(/\d+ \w+/)[0] === time.text().match(/\d+ \w+/)[0]){
      // "white out" the dates that match
     nextTime.html(nextTime.text().replace(/(\d+ \w+)/, "<font color=\"white\">$1</font>"))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule" data-timezone="et">         /* The value of data-timezone attribute changes on button click from the Screenshot below */ 

   <!-- List of button start -->
   <div class="schedule-action-bar">
      <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
         Select your timezone:            
         <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-et" class="" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- List of button end -->

    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
             
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août  03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août  03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .schedule-show -->
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .schedule-show -->
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
              <time datetime="05:00 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    05:00</time>            /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->

</div>
```

Comment: Don't use font tags.....

Comment: To further elaborate, `<font>` hasn't been in HTML since HTML4.01, from 1998. We removed it from the spec literally 20 years ago =)

Comment: Having said that, the first candidate when regexp are involved is _always_ the regexp. What do you think `/\d+ \w+/` does on your French content? (e.g. what do you think `\w` does, and why would that be good enough for your needs?)

Comment: @epascarello Which tag should I use then ?

Comment: you should use CSS, not "a tag". Write some classes that define your font/colors/etc and then add them to the element that needs to use them.

Comment: In your regular expression, `\w` doesn't match characters with diacritics.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression, `\w` doesn't match characters with accents (diacritics).  See [Concrete Javascript Regex for Accented Characters (Diacritics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics)

You can replace your regular expression `\w` with `[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]`

```js
// we have to iterate backwards...
$($('.schedule-show').get().reverse()).each(function(i, div){
 let time = $(div).find('[data-timezone="et"]')
  let nextTime = $(div).find('+ .schedule-show [data-timezone="et"]')
  if(nextTime[0]){
   // check if they dates match
    if(nextTime.text().match(/\d+ \w+/)[0] === time.text().match(/\d+ \w+/)[0]){
      // "white out" the dates that match
     nextTime.html(nextTime.text().replace(/(\d+ [A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)/, "<font color=\"white\">$1</font>"))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule" data-timezone="et">         /* The value of data-timezone attribute changes on button click from the Screenshot below */ 

   <!-- List of button start -->
   <div class="schedule-action-bar">
      <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
         Select your timezone:            
         <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-et" class="" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- List of button end -->

    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
             
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août  03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août  03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 01-08-2019" data-timezone="et">1 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .schedule-show -->
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
               <time datetime="03:45 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .schedule-show -->
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
              <time datetime="05:00 02-08-2019" data-timezone="et">2 août    05:00</time>            /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->

</div>
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for the help. I think this problem is coming because of special characters in french. I am wondering if its gonna work for these months as well `février`  `décembre` ?

Comment: Yes, if you modify the regular expression as I showed, you should be good with the other french month names.  The problem was that `\d+ \w+` was matching only `2 ao` and ending before the `û` in `août`.  Try it online https://regex101.com/r/VzxtYW/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like to be in the regexp `\w` not matching accentuated letters.

You could either:

- simply, **first** unaccentuate Date and time **before** check regexp, see for example [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)
- or, make the regexp compatible with accents, [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). See [Concrete Javascript Regex for Accented Characters (Diacritics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics), or [What's a good regex to include accented characters in a simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676691/whats-a-good-regex-to-include-accented-characters-in-a-simple-way/48925757), or any equivalent