# What's a good regex to include accented characters as well?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex validator in python that included accented characters for instance in French, however, I cannot find a valid regex pattern that does this. I have already tried: [What's a good regex to include accented characters in a simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676691/whats-a-good-regex-to-include-accented-characters-in-a-simple-way/48925757)

But I still cannot validate `ådam` for instance I basically want all alphanumeric characters plus `-` , space and apostrophe included but the regex I used is not working:

`(?i)^(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿ ])+$`

Comment: The example works when I try it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/teTifr/1)?

Comment: Why don't you use `\w` and `UNICODE` flag? Yes, this character class will be wider than just French accented letters, but you ought to be multicultural these days.

Comment: @Timus for instance it does not support `ßloc`

Comment: @ashes999 That's due to the negative lookahead `(?![×Þß÷þø])` (or am I missing something?)

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of text you want your code to handle. The correct way involves normalizing the input, and use `regex` package with full case folding to match the text, since there could be cases where one visible character consists of 2 or more Unicode character - the base character and composing characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `re` module with the following expression:

```
^(?:[^\W_]|[ '-])+$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^\W_]|[ '-])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[^\W_]` - any letter or digit
  - `|`  - or
  - `[ '-]` - space, apostrophe
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX4FaJ/1)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by importing `regex` package and using Unicode category `\p{L}` to match any kind of letter from any language. Apostrophe, spaces, hyphens and digits `0-9` are also matched.

```
import regex

string = "abcd ßloc ådam - + * 1 2 3 ''×Þß÷þø À-ÿ"
pattern = r"[\p{L}\d-' ]+"
result = regex.findall(pattern, string)

print(result)

# OUTPUT
# ['abcd ßloc ådam - ', ' ', " 1 2 3 ''", 'Þß', 'þø À-ÿ']
```