# Remove all characters without a-z and polish chars in php

Tags: php

im struggling with program, that deletes all characters, and left only a-z chars and polish chars: ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż. So what i want to do is delete all chars like spaces, dots, numbers, those fancy non printable characters, etc. and create another string with what's left.
Thanks in advance.

```
Example:
Input: "111',///[asdżźć';p],,."
Output: "asdżźćp"
```

Comment: A `preg_replace_all` would do the trick. So you want to delete ANY character except for plain a-z?

Comment: a-z and polish chars like ó,ż,ź,ć, and i don't feel like specifying all possible chars, especially non printable chars, to cut out  is a good idea, or maybe i misunderstood how preg_replace works.

Comment: You need to define exactly which characters you want to remain. PHP (and most of the readers here) won't know what _"Polish characters like..."_ means

Comment: I specified four examples, but i understand the point. Here is a list of polish chars:  ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.

Comment: @Chwistuniu is it lowercaps only or also uppercaps?

Comment: Only lowercaps.

Comment: That should show you how to remove characters. Then just update characters in character class.

Comment: @Javid It is just `preg_replace`, only `preg_match` has the `all` variation.

Comment: @user3783243 yes, thank you, this works well, I don't know how to mark your answer as correct, but it solves the problem.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676691/whats-a-good-regex-to-include-accented-characters-in-a-simple-way/48925757

Comment: So after some searching, i made this: ```$text = mb_strtolower($text); $txt_search = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9ąćęłńóśźż]/iu',"", $text);``` , and it may not be correct usage but works, so thats ok for me. The solution from link is good if you want to allow more chars for specific languages like russian(because it leaves chars like latin tilde), and for strings with lower and upper case letters.