# MySQL search - escape special characters from column

Tags: php, mysql, regex, string

Hi I want to search string by escaping special characters using Like query.

**My String is** - abc & abc

**Column value is** - abc & abc

Somehow I don't want to include special characters in this search functionality.

I can escape my string using `REGEX` by using `preg_replace with /[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/`

What I want is some mysql function which can replace the column value for getting search result only but it should not update the column value.

So I will pass abc abc string and it will match column with value abc abc.

Virtually - `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myColumn LIKE 'abc abc';`

and it should give me the result.

Comment: basically you want to ignore all special characters in where clause?

Comment: You need to review your question. First you talk about "escape" and then you suggest `preg_replace` (escape != replace). Again you talk about "search" and then "should not update".

Comment: I will use preg replace to ignore all characters from my string using php and then it will match using like clause

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string. You need to write a custom function to replace all special chars to blank/space

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS RemoveSpecialChar; 

DELIMITER $ 

CREATE FUNCTION RemoveSpecialChar(in_str VARCHAR(4096)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) CHARSET utf8 
BEGIN 


 DECLARE out_str VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT ''; 


DECLARE c VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT ''; 


DECLARE pointer INT DEFAULT 1;
  IF ISNULL(in_str) THEN 
    RETURN NULL; 


ELSE 
    WHILE pointer <= LENGTH(in_str) DO



          SET c = MID(in_str, pointer, 1); 


          IF ASCII(c) NOT IN(35, 38,37, 42, 64, 94) THEN 
                SET out_str = CONCAT(out_str, c); 
          END IF; 

          SET pointer = pointer + 1; 
        END WHILE;   END IF; 

  RETURN out_str; 

END$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

below query is working

```
SELECT RemoveSpecialChar(loginPass) FROM users
```

You need to add ascii value of all required character  in below if of function

```
 IF ASCII(c) NOT IN(35, 38,37, 42, 64, 94) THEN
```

So your query will be

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myColumn LIKE RemoveSpecialChar('abc & abc')
```

Comment: I executed the above successfully. Now it is giving me error - FUNCTION testdb.RemoveSpecialChar does not exist

Comment: updated my answer, check now. I have also changed function definition.