# Sorting words by its occurence in a database, matching similar words

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table it has lot of words on it.

- Hai.
- Am i
- hai
- joe
- This
- Those
- hai

In at above example "hi" is occurring three times I want to create a query which will look at this table and sort out most occurred words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause and `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT word, COUNT(*) count FROM your_table GROUP BY word ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,3;
```

Possible output:

```
+------+-------+
| word | count |
+------+-------+
| hai  | 2     |
| Hai. | 1     |
| This | 1     |
+------+-------+
```

If you want MySQL to treat `hai` and `Hai.` as the same word, you should strip all non-alpha characters before grouping. See [MySQL: how to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6942973/878514). Then, based on method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22903586/878514) it will look like this:

```
SELECT LOWER(alphanum(word)) word, COUNT(*) count FROM your_table 
GROUP BY LOWER(alphanum(word)) ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,3;
```

And possible result:

```
+------+-------+
| word | count |
+------+-------+
| hai  | 3     |
| this | 1     |
| joe  | 1     |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: If i want to include the words which are seems like similar means what to do?.

Comment: In at above out put basically hai and Hai are similar if i want to count hai and Hai are same what to do?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compose a sql statement using the `group by` method that will group like things together. Something like this should get you started

```
select word, count(word) 
from table 
group by word 
order by count(word) desc
```