# SELECT to match special characters and case

Tags: mysql, regex, select

Field **X** in **table** may contain special characters e.g **hello!World** and I would like to know if there is a way to match that with **HelloWorld** (Ignore case and special characters).
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE X='Helloworld'`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find non-ASCII characters in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql)

Comment: @Alexey I don't think is the same

Comment: @Stefanos Chrs have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to replace all special characters like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(X, '!', '')) = LOWER('HelloWorld');
```

Chain those replacements if you have to replace more:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(X, '!', ''), '?', '')) = LOWER('HelloWorld');
```

Comment: and then yet thousand REPLACE() calls :) Sorry, I did not realize there was reasonable number of "special" characters meant in the original post. As a generic solution I don't think it works well

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2afa1/1

if you need exaclty match of string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE x REGEXP '^hello[[:punct:],[:space:]]world$';
```

And if `hello world` could be a part of larger string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE x REGEXP 'hello[[:punct:],[:space:]]world';
```

Comment: The thing is I don't know where the Special Character will be in the string, @fancyPants answer did the trick

Comment: that is up to you, you should clarify better next time when ask. My answer is exactly what you was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you need to filter out non-ASCII characters? Please confirm whether this is true. In order to do that, have a look at REGEXP matching as in the comment link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql) question.

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM `table ` WHERE `X` REGEXP 'Helloworld';
```

Comment: `Helloworld` doesn't match `hello!World`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't do the trick, I still don't get the row

Comment: @Toto: you're right, the answer is not right. Not sure if it's better to delete it. There was a discussion on filtering non-alpha characters here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string . As the accepted answer says it's better to store filtered values. Then we don't need to filter every row on every query (huge performance drawback) and it can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP 'hello[^[:alpha:]]*world'
```

Notes:

- This finds the string in the middle of other stuff; add ^ and $ to anchor to ends.
- This assumes the non-alpha character(s) are between `hello` and `world`, not some other spot in the string.
- This relies on the relevant collation to do (or not do) case folding.

Comment: The thing is I don't know where the Special Character will be in the string, @fancyPants answer did the trick