# 100-1000+ Term Search For Lucene / Sphinx / Mysql

Tags: mysql, search, lucene

I'm currently building a database that will monitor company records. I need to search for MANY (we're talking potentially a few thousand when it's finished) company names against a single column in a table where the company names will be listed. I currently use the following basic mysql LIKE query (this is condensed, the current one has 300+ terms being searched for):

```
SELECT * FROM "case-file-owner" WHERE "party-name" LIKE 'Nike%' OR
"party-name" LIKE 'Lyon Group Inc.%' OR "party-name" LIKE 'Target Home%'
ORDER BY "party-name" ASC
```

As you can see, it's a bit basic! How would you do a search like this with Lucene or Sphinx? Are these tools overkill for this task? While I need to search for potentially thousands of companies, the current setup only searches a table containing maybe 1000 records each day (I run a query that cuts out records I don't need to search).

My primary issue revolves around minor issues. For example: Company1, Inc. Company1 Inc. The Company1 Inc. The Company1 Incorporated. are all possible representations of many company names I need to find.

Would MATCH work? Would a gigantic query like this take forever with Lucene or Sphinx? My current LIKE search is "optimized" by dumping any leading wildcard operators... but hardly intelligent!

Answer (score 1):

> My primary issue revolves around minor issues. For example: Company1, Inc. Company1 Inc. The Company1 Inc. The Company1 Incorporated. are all possible representations of many company names I need to find.

In general, you will run into problems trying to pattern match variable manifestations of company names.  There's a very real chance that you will produce false positives.  For example 'Nike%' might mean to search for variants related to Nike Shoes, but would also match Nikeno Inc (if there were such a company).

If possible, I would suggest adding a column normalized-party-name where you store a single search term that represents each company, e.g.

```
normalized-party-name  party-name
COMPANY INC            Company1, Inc. 
COMPANY INC            Company1 Inc. 
COMPANY INC            The Company1 Inc.
```

> The biggest issue however is the sleight variations like commas, periods, etc. I can create multiple company name variations fairly easily

You can remove all punctuation from the normalized name.  You might also try using Sphinx with the [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) [morphology](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-morphology.html).  Soundex ignores punctuation when looking for a match.  You could then use the [extended](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/extended-syntax.html) [matching mode](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/matching-modes.html) to search just the unique variants you get ignoring punctuation.  Lucerne may have something similar, but I have not worked with it.

Comment: I can't do this. I do not control data entry, these are public records :(

Comment: Can you then create a table on your end that maps a normalized name to the public-record name and join to your own table when doing this type of filtering?

Comment: I suppose I could add my own table - I've rebuilt their database locally. The biggest issue however is the sleight variations like commas, periods, etc. I can create multiple company name variations fairly easily for the saved queries. I suppose running a command to remove these characters would be a start. How would I do that for multiple rows? I assume an actual editing command followed by a search would work faster than trying to manipulate a string, then search, over and over.

As for Lucene, wouldn't that be easier? I feel like it should be a better option.

Comment: I'm gonna look into sphinx more for this. One issue I see though is mapping the non-normal name to the normal name. It would need to be a manual thing built beforehand, correct?

Comment: For anyone reading this, I found a cool function that sanitizes strings of all non-alphanumeric characters:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string