# MySQL procedure to remove special characters, except alphanumeric characters and spaces M

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table with a column abc that has some special characters like ",.` . I want to remove those and clean up the column using a stored procedure. I have looked up online (
[How to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string))  and found that the below function that works. But, I need a procedure that I can execute to clean up the column. 
I am very new to programming and MySQL and using phpMyAdmin to create a routine. Any help on coverting the below and validating would be of great help.

```html
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphanum; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION alphanum( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(16) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ;
```

Also, How would I run it ?  Should I just create a routine and then just use the call statement to clean up the colum ?

Comment: Have you created this function? Mysql procedure call statement is `Call procedure_name()` and function call statement is `SELECT functionName()`

Comment: I was reading a little and it says that function has a return value and procedure does not...so, to cleanse data, I need to use procedure. I have not created it yet, wanted to see, if I just create the routine in myphpadmin  ?

Comment: How frequent do you want to call that procedure to do the cleansing job?

Answer (score 0):

Just write `Update` to clean up column values with the help of function you have in question.

Assuming you have table name as `table1` and column `abc`

```
UPDATE table1
SET abc=alphanum(abc);
```

This will update table column `abc` with new value.

Put this query in your procedure.

Comment: Well, I am not sure, if I should directly put it. My understanding after reading is that, functions have return values and procedures are meant to carry out an action. How would I have a return value here where I want to cleanse data ?

Comment: Stored procedures not returns as functions. Anyway if you want to get something from it like number of rows updated then put `select row_count();` just after the update statement to get the affected rows.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong I do not want to return anything. I just want to cleanse data. My goal is to have a procedure and execute it so that it cleanses data. Thats the question. The info I shared is for function and it requires that there is a return value for that...But, I do not want that. Does it make sense ?