# Formatting String data in an SQL Select Search

Tags: mysql, sql, select, resultset, format-string

I'm honestly not sure how to phrase this. So I'm just going to explain the issue

In order to find as many possible matches as possible, I currently run a piece of code that converts data to upper case, removes spaces and invalid characters. For example:

`Hi there, I'm very happy! -> HITHEREIMVERYHAPPY`

My database is reaching a size where it's no longer efficient to run the piece of code that checks each line in a `ResultSet`, so I was wondering if this is possible in `SQL` somehow?

`SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").replace(" ", "").toUpperCase() = INPUT AND Response.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").replace(" ", "").toUpperCase() = RESPONSE`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database (and version) that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server... String functions are quite vendor-specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-mysql)

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like [RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) for this.

> ```
> -- Sample data
> create table Data
> (
>   Id int primary key auto_increment,
>   Input varchar(100),
>   Response varchar(100)
> );
> insert into Data (Input, Response) values
>   ('Hi there, I''m very happy! ->', 'To have 1 solution.')
> , ('HITHEREIMVERYHAPPY', 'ToHave1Solution')
> , ('I rlike this', 'IRLikeThis')
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM Data
> WHERE Input RLIKE '[^ A-Za-z0-9]'
>   AND Response RLIKE '[^ A-Za-z0-9]'
> ```

**Result:**

> ```
> Id | Input                        | Response           
> -: | :--------------------------- | :------------------
>  1 | Hi there, I'm very happy! -> | To have 1 solution.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=435a1ca18d35ee698b925f049830d09f)*

It basically uses the regex `[^ A-Za-z0-9]`, which matches strings that contain any character that's not a letter, digit or space.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a replace of the spaces...

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REPLACE(TABLE.COLUMN,' ','') = VALUE;

Comment: Is there any way to implement regex for the illegal characters though?

Comment: This has already been asnwered here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-mysql